# ls and grep from different directory

Tags: shell, grep, ls

I got the following directories :

```
.
|__ scripts
|    
|__ logs
```

In my `logs` folder, I got files formated this way :

```
AAAAAAA_X1-09-09-2018.log
BBBBBBB_Y2-09-09-2018.log
CCCCCCC_Z3-09-09-2018.log
```

When I run the command `ls | grep AAAAAAA*.log"` from `logs` it works fine :

```
user /my/path/logs #> ls | grep AAAA*log
AAAAAAA_X1-09-09-2018.log
```

But if ran from `scripts` directory, I got no match :

```
user /my/path/scripts #>  ls ../logs | grep AAAAA*log
```

I noticed that the command `ls ../logs | grep AAAAA*` would work, but I have to force the `.log` to be matched (other files being generated in that directory sometimes). I can fix this issue by doing :

`ls ../logs | grep AAAAA* | grep log`

but I wonder, why `ls ../logs | grep AAAAA*log` doesn't work from `scripts` but `logs` ?

Comment: `grep AAAA*log` is really just `grep AAAAAAA_X1-09-09-2018.log`. The `*` is exapanded BEFORE the grep is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better change directory to `log` like below first:-

```
cd /full/path/log
ls | grep AAAA*log
cd - #go back to the original path
```

Modify above in your script and try.

Also try to follow the instruction given by Kamil Cuk.

Comment: Well, it seems [Kamil is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254898/ls-and-grep-from-different-directory#comment91457382_52254898), so no need to use a regex if wildcard search is enough.